# Epochs definition in Neural networks

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I have a doubt about the epoch definition in Neural Networks. Wanting to train a DNN model setting the parameter epochs (e.g. in Keras) to 100 is the same thing of setting it to 1, train the model, save it and then repeat the step loading the previously saved model for other 99 times?

Comment: setting ```model.fit(epoch=1) ``` is not the same as setting the epoch to 100. if you set it to one means that you will just read the x_train set one time only. However, 100 means the model will loop through the x_train set 100 times. Each time you are loading the weights you have saved before( you can also save the best model in Keras ) and after each epoch, the weight is being changed based on the optimizer you are using (adam for example). Let me know if i got you right

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have some doubts. I try to clarify through this code: `model.fit(epoch=100)` is the same of `for i in range(0, 100): model = load.model(...) model.fit(epoch=1) model.save(...)`?

Comment: By the way, the parameter in fit is called epochs (plural), not epoch.

Comment: This question is not about programming. Please ask at https://ai.stackexchange.com/. Thanks.